# How to prevent decode encodeURIComponent in address bar in mobile device? Google Blogger Error - Pagination is not working correct in mobile device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, xml, blogger

Please read carefully. The problem is coming in the Google Blogger template. Pagination are not working properly in the mobile devices. It is working fine in the Desktop and tablet mode. The pagination is the code of JavaScript.

I tried to find the issue and I got that - "URL is not encoding in the address bar in the mobile mode". That's why the pagination buttons are not showing as per the number of pages. Due to this blogger unable to read the proper url in address bar. See below example

Correct Encoded Address in Desktop- https://www.example.com/search?updated-max=2019-06-25T21%3A53%3A00%2B05%3A30&max-results=4

Incorrect Address in Mobile - https://www.example.com/search?updated-max=2019-06-25T21:53:00%2B05:30&max-results=4&m=1

2019-06-25T21:53:00+05:30 This part of URL in Address Bar should be encoded.

Means 2019-06-25T21:53:00+05:30 should be 2019-06-25T21%3A53%3A00%2B05%3A30 in Mobile same as Desktop. But the colon(:) is not encoding in %3A. This is the main issue.

If I manually edit the URL in address bar and write %3A instead of colon(:) and press the enter, then it is working correct.

I debug the JavaScript Code from the chrom developer tool. I applied the breakpoint here  f = encodeURIComponent(f); Then I got that - the encoding is working fine in Desktop and Mobile too. This is shocking.

So, what's the problem? Why the URL is not encoding in the address bar in Mobile mode? 90% I guess that - the Encoded URL part is again Decoding in mobile mode. Means colon(:) is encoding in %3A then again decoding in colon(:) in mobile mode.

This is the problem analysis by me. But I may be wrong. I haven't much stronger knowledge of JS. This kind of issue is shocking and facing first time.

```
<script>
    /*JavaScript Code of Pagination*/
    var pageNaviConf = {
        perPage: 4,
        numPages: 4,
        firstText: "First ",
        lastText: "Last ",
        nextText: "Next ",
        prevText: "Prev "
    }

    //<![CDATA[

    function pageNavi(o) {
        var m = location.href,
            l = m.indexOf("/search/label/") != -1,
            a = l ? m.substr(m.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14, m.length) : "";
            a = a.indexOf("?") != -1 ? a.substr(0, a.indexOf("?")) : a;
            var g = l ? "/search/label/" + a + "?updated-max=" : "/search?updated-max=",
            k = o.feed.entry.length,
            e = Math.ceil(k / pageNaviConf.perPage);
            if (e <= 1) {
                return
             }

             var n = 1,
             h = [""];
             l ? h.push("/search/label/" + a + "?max-results=" + pageNaviConf.perPage) : h.push("/?max-results=" + pageNaviConf.perPage);

             for (var d = 2; d <= e; d++) {
                 var c = (d - 1) * pageNaviConf.perPage - 1,
                 b = o.feed.entry[c].published.$t,
                 f = b.substring(0, 19) + b.substring(23, 29);
                 f = encodeURIComponent(f);

                 if (m.indexOf(f) != -1) {
                     n = d
                 }

                 h.push(g + f + "&max-results=" + pageNaviConf.perPage)
             }

             pageNavi.show(h, n, e)
         }

         pageNavi.show = function(f, e, a) {
             var d = Math.floor((pageNaviConf.numPages - 1) / 2),        
             g = pageNaviConf.numPages - 1 - d,
             c = e - d;
             if (c <= 0) {
                 c = 1
             }

             endPage = e + g;
             if ((endPage - c) < pageNaviConf.numPages) {
                 endPage = c + pageNaviConf.numPages - 1
             }
             if (endPage > a) {
                 endPage = a;
                 c = a - pageNaviConf.numPages + 1
             }
             if (c <= 0) {
                 c = 1
             }
             var b = '<span class="pages">Pages ' + e + ' of ' + a + " 
             </span> ";
             if(c > 1){
                 b += '<a href="' + f[1] + '">' + pageNaviConf.firstText 
                 + "</a>"
             }

             if (e > 1) {
                 b += '<a href="' + f[e - 1] + '">' + 
                 pageNaviConf.prevText + "</a>"
             }

             if (e < a) {
                 b += '<a href="' + f[e + 1] + '">' + 
                 pageNaviConf.nextText + "</a>"
             }

             if (endPage < a) {
                 b += '<a href="' + f[a] + '">' + pageNaviConf.lastText + 
                 " </a>"
             }

             document.write(b)
         };

         (function() {
             var b = location.href;
             if (b.indexOf("?q=") != -1 || b.indexOf(".html") != -1) {
                 return
             }

             var d = b.indexOf("/search/label/") + 14;

             if (d != 13) {
                 var c = b.indexOf("?"),
                 a = (c == -1) ? b.substring(d) : b.substring(d, c);

                 document.write('<script type="text/javascript" 
                 src="/feeds/posts/summary/-/' + a + '?alt=json-in-script&callback=pageNavi&max-results=99999"><\/script>')
             }
             else {
                 document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/summary?alt=json-in-script&callback=pageNavi&max-results=99999"><\/script>')
             }

         })()
    //]]>

</script>
```

Overall our target is to Encode colon(:) into %3A in address bar in Mobile. I couldn't find any strong solution on the internet. I humble request to please look for it briefly and fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is unreadable. Like a pretty printed minified script. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: This is the actual code. I can't reduce  the code more. I've  written  the code with proper indentation. Please read it briefly, you'll catch it. And must, please read the problem description carefully, if  you didn't.